# Pycharm path issues

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Im testing the very first line of a text extraction program in Python with PyCharm. With only a couple lines of simple code, the editor is raising errors on nearly every word

Ive done some googling about path configuration and tried reading the official documentation as well. I think is has something to do with `Working Directory`? But I can't find a clear definition for the term and dont want to sabotage myself by ignorantly messing with path variables

```py
import os

test = os.listdir(
       /Users/.../Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common/Europa Universalis IV/history/countries
)

print(test)
```

The errors are: `UNUSED IMPORT STATEMENT` and `UNRESOLVED REFERENCE` (on every term in the path and os)

What am I doing wrong? I imported and used a different module this afternoon with 0 issues on a separate file. Ive changed none of the interpreter or config settings between the last file and this one.

Comment: Do you have a Project Interpreter configured?

Comment: It solved half my problem. Now I'm not getting any errors until I run the code, but it says it cannot find the file even tho I copied the path directly from the file in Finder.

Answer (score 0):

In pycharm, you need to go to File -> Settings -> Under Project(current project name) -> Project Structure and "Add Content Root" of all the directories that you import your files from.
[image: On the right hand side]

And make sure you check the option for "add content roots to PYTHONPATH"(File-> Settings-> Python Console from the Console dropdown) as following:
[image]